# R: Select only one element in each row that meets a specific criteria

Tags: r, select, dataframe

I have a `data frame` that looks like this

```
x <- data.frame("a.1" = c(NA, NA, 101, 101, NA),
                "a.2" = c(NA, NA, 101, NA, NA),
                "a.3" = c(101, NA, NA, NA, 103),
                "a.4" = c(NA, NA , NA, NA, 103))
```

Each row contains either `NA`'s and/or some `10x` value. This value is unique to each row, such that one row cannot contain e.g. `101` and `103` at the same time.

Now I want to create a column containing the value found in each row, irrespective of whether it appears one or many times. Each row that has only `NA` should also have `NA`. In my case this should look like this

```
   new column
1  101
2  NA
3  101
4  101
5  103
```

Any idea how I can do this in *an efficient way*! My orginial data frame is pretty large so I'd like to avoid computationally expensive `for`-loops and murky `ifelse` statements.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Using `rowMeans()` is a pretty nice solution as @akrun pointed out. However, in my orginial data set, the values 101, 102, ... are in fact character strings indicating some industry. I could, of course, convert them via `as.numeric`, yet I have some industry indicators with leading zeros such as `013`, `0201` etc. Those zeros get killed (logically) when converted to numeric, hence I cannot convert them.

What to do in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
 x$newcolumn <- do.call(pmax, c(x, list(na.rm=TRUE)))
 x$newcolumn
 #[1] 101  NA 101 101 103
```

Or another option is `rowMeans` as there is only a single unique element in a row.

```
rowMeans(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

#### Update

If the columns are `character` class and don't want to convert to `numeric`, one option is `max.col`

```
x1[cbind(1:nrow(x1),max.col(!is.na(x1), 'first'))]
#[1] "012" NA    "012" "011" "011"
```

The `pmax` approach should also work

```
do.call(pmax, c(x1, na.rm=TRUE))
#[1] "012" NA    "012" "011" "011"
```

#### data

```
x1 <- data.frame(a.1 = c(NA, NA, '012', '011', NA),
            a.2 = c(NA, NA, '012', NA, NA),
            a.3 = c('012', NA, NA, NA, '011'),
            a.4 = c(NA, NA , NA, NA, '011'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks!  `rowMeans()` is exaclty what i was looking for as it is clean and pretty fast. This is perfect. `do.call` I never really understood, so I'm glad to avoid it :-)

Comment: @ManuelS Thank you for the comments.  `pmax` should be also fast.

Comment: @ akrun I redrew the "accepted" answer, as I have a new issue. Will reaccept though, since it worked well for the original question.

Comment: @ManuelS  Updated the post, please check if that helps

Comment: OP why would you withdraw the accepted answer when one of the solutions worked for both cases?

Comment: @PierreLafortune  I am guessing that the OP didn't try the `pmax` solution

Comment: They are wasting people's time by not trying the solutions provided and complaining that they do not work.

Comment: Oh indeed. My bad. Sorry for that. I assumed the `pmax` solution only works on numeric rows...

Comment: The `pmax` solution is indeed very nice! Thanks, and sorry for my carelessness!

Comment: @ManuelS It's okay.  I thought you were trying with `rowMeans` and got confused what to do with `character` strings.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found a solution using `apply`, `lapply` and `ifelse`` statement...not as clean as I would like it but its reasonably fast and works

```
 x1 <- data.frame(a.1 = c(NA, NA, '012', '011', NA),
        a.2 = c(NA, NA, '012', NA, NA),
        a.3 = c('012', NA, NA, NA, '011'),
        a.4 = c(NA, NA , NA, NA, '011'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

new.column  <- x1 %>% 
   apply(1, function(i) unique(i[!is.na(i)])) %>% 
   lapply(function(i) ifelse(length(i) == 0, NA, i)) %>% 
   unlist()
```